# SOAP logging error in( Eclipse) JAVA program

Tags: java, logging, soap, log4j, slf4j

Getting these errors while trying to enable logging (SOAP logs).

**SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.**

POM file that I'm using has the below lines :

```
*<!-- Adds the log4j framework -->
 <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.16</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- Make SLF4J use JDK logging as the logging framework -->
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>*
```

Can anyone help me get the SOAP logs ?
Thanks in advnace !

Comment: You can simply follow the follwing tutorial
https://mkyong.com/logging/apache-log4j-2-tutorials/

Without looking at your pom.xml, property file, and code, its difficult to judge what did you do wrong

Comment: The error message that you have posted has nothing to with SOAP web service. It simply states that the logger could not found an actual implementation of logging framework (in your classpath) that you are using in your code